# What does it mean blue line on Xcode code editor

Tags: xcode, editor

I know that red line on the right side of the code editor means error, yellow line warning, but what about blue line?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines mean that there is a Breakpoint in that line. [image].